# Query all posts under one taxonomy? Why is my code not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, taxonomy, tax-query

I'm trying to show all the posts associated with a Taxonomy (not a term) but it seems to not work.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'clients',
            'terms' => 'Unilever'
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_query();
$the_query->query($args);

if($the_query->have_posts()):while($the_query->have_posts()):$the_query->the_post();

php the_title();


endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: You should use wp_reset_post_data instead of wp_reset_query when using WP_Query objects   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the 'field' value e.g. `'field' => 'slug',`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for the answer:

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'clients'
    )
);